# How do I put pure HTML in a .jsx (NextJS) website?

Tags: javascript, next.js

i want to put razorpay code in nextjs website, but its in pure html. e.g.- `<form><script src="https://cdn.razorpay.com/static/widget/subscription-button.js" data-subscription_button_id="pl_I3alndvIjA9dQW" data-button_theme="brand-color" async> </script> </form>`

how to insert in in NextJS (JSX or TSX file).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `next/script` on [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script#inline-scripts)

```
import Script from 'next/script'

 ...Code

<Script
   id="someId"
   dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `<form><script src="https://cdn.razorpay.com/static/widget/subscription-button.js" data-subscription_button_id="pl_I3alndvIjA9dQW" data-button_theme="brand-color" async> </script> </form>`
   }}

/>
```